# How to run multiple pytorch layers in parallel, when they are of the same graph depth?

Tags: python, deep-learning, parallel-processing, pytorch, simd

Implementing [this paper (ROCKET)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.13051), I ended up with [this code](https://github.com/noamzilo/timeseries_classification_random_conv/blob/master/EcgModel.py), which works.

The main issue I have with it is in summary **How to run multiple pytorch layers in parallel, when they are of the same graph depth?**

In the paper, 10000 convolutions with different (randomized) parameters are used on the same input to create 10000 corresponding feature maps, on which simple feature extractors are used.

Implementing this simplifies to

```
class MyModel(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        num_kernels = 10000
        for _ in range(num_kernels):       
            self.convs[_] = nn.Conv1d(...)


    def forward(...):
          for i, layer in enumerate(self.convs):
              res = layer(data)
```

This just runs a Pythonic 10000-for-loop, each iteration runs its corresponding convolution.

How do I utilize Pytorch to run those 10000 convolutions efficiently, without waiting for each one to end before dispatching the next one?

This also generalizes for any non-fully-sequential Pytorch models.

Comment: Are you running on GPU or CPU? If your code runs on a GPU then these should already be computed asynchronously as long as you're not doing something like printing the output or transferring tensors to CPU in the loop. You can read more about this [in the docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#asynchronous-execution).

Comment: Why don't you just use the `out_channels` parameter of Conv1d to run the 10k kernels with a single conv layer?

Comment: @iacolippo as I said, the parameters are all different, so can't do that.